# iOS program to use multiple UITableView in a single UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, multiple-tables

I am trying to implement 3 tables in a single segue in a storyboard.
When one table is selected it will unhidden a view with another table and likewise one more.
The following code i have used for one table the cell format of each table is different and rows also vary. So how can i DIFFERENTIATE between each table by coding to set different number of rows for each table and so on?

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  3;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell1==nil)
{
    cell1=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
    temp=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *Label1 = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:4];
    Label1.text = temp.Title;
    UILabel *Label2 = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:6];
    Label2.text = temp.Title;
    UITextField *textfield1 = (UITextField *)[cell1 viewWithTag:5];
    textfield1.text =temp.description;
    UILabel *Label3 = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:7];
    Label3.text = temp.Title;
    return cell1;
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.showlist=[[ShowList alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShowList" bundle:nil];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    ShowlistIndex=indexPath.row;
    _secondview.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: Rather than put all the `UITableView`s into a single `UIViewController`, create one `UIViewController` and 3 `UITableViewController`s. Add each `UITableViewController` as a child view controller of the `UITableViewController`. This allows you to implement each `UITableViewController` separately, without a bunch of if/else if's in each of the table view delegate methods.

Comment: @bobnoble 
I thought of that but i has some problems to implement a child view controller. Haven't done it before. That is why i tried to put it inside sub views. Anyway thanks for the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should declare your `tableViews` in `.h` file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *firstTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *secondTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *thirdTableView;
```

And then all the delegate methods have variable with pointing witch object call this method, so you can check:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == self.firstTableView)
       return  3;
   else if(tableView == self.secondTableView)
       return 4;
   else if(tableView == self.thirdTableView)
      return 100;
}
```

The other delegate methods work in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the different tableviews using class properties e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView3;
```

In the delegate methods you can check for the correct tableView e.g.:

```
if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
    // add code for tableView1
} else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
    // add code for tableView2
} else if (tableView == self.tableView3) {
    // add code for tableView3
} else {
    // unknown tableView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the tableview reference in each of your delegate methods right? You can find out which tableview you are currently walking through based on that..

Assuming..

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
```

Ex:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableView == tableView1)
      return 1;
    if(tableView == tableView2)
      return 5;
    return 10;
}
```

You can do the same for the other delegate methods..
I hope I understood your question correctly..

Answer (score 0):

you nedd to create 3 uitableview outlets. and then you can identifies tableviews by specifyin tag. for example tableview1.tag=1, tableview.tag=2 etc.

then in tableview methods you can use it. for example.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if(tableView.tag==1){
return  3;
}
else if(tableView=2)
{return 3;}
}
```

may be this help.

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 4.1

4.1 is a version which i wrote the code. It might be worked in the other version of swift. I'm not sure.

---

***Firstly*** , right click to the **tableViewContent1 and tableViewContent2** and drag it to **dataSource and
 delegate** into **View Controller** like this image below.
[image]

---

***Secondly*** , you can implement as my code below.
* I've already set the both label in tableViewContent1 and tableViewContent2 with tag = 1000 .

---

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewContent1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewContent2: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

---

```
extension ViewController :
UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == tableViewContent1 {
            // in order to make the tableViewContent1 get 5 rows.
            return 5
        }
        else{
            // in order to make the tableViewContent2 get 3 rows.
            return 3
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.tableViewContent1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "content1", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellFirstCustom 
            let label : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel{
                lab.text = "to change label in content1."
            }
            return cell
        }

        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "content2", for: indexPath)  
            let label : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
            label.text = "to change label in content2."
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

---

after that you will get result like image below.
It worked for me.
[image]