# how to load two tableview in same view controller with cell for index row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i am facing one module consists to load two different `UITableView` in same `UIViewController` i know where i doing mistake, the problem is cell for row AtIndexpath in table view method. i getting only one `UITableView` in `UIViewController` but my secondviewcontroller not return any values in             cell.

here my sample code for ur reference:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView==table) {
     return [self.arryData count];
}
else
return [tblArr count];
NSLog(@"tabeCount==>%lu",(unsigned long)tblArr.count);

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 55;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";

       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITableViewCell *cell;
mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *plan_cell;

if (tableView==table) {
    cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}return cell;

if (tableView==planTable) {

    plan_cell =  [self.planTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    if (plan_cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        plan_cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    plan_cell.label.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Answer1"];
    plan_cell.Label2.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer2"];
    plan_cell.Label3.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer3"];
    plan_cell.label4.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer4"];

 }
    return plan_cell;
}
  - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

 }
```

Comment: Your second view controller or second tableview? please explain

Comment: You can use 2 different custom cells in one tableview.

Comment: second tableview dude

Comment: @Anand- Please set tag to both tableView and and no need to write double   return statement.

Comment: @Anand-   See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928295/ios-program-to-use-multiple-uitableview-in-a-single-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made the small mistake just change the `Return Cell` in inside the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


 static NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"Cell";
if (tableView==table) {


UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.textLabel.text = [self.arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
else {



  mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *plan_cell =  [self.planTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
if (plan_cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    plan_cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

plan_cell.label.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Answer1"];
plan_cell.Label2.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer2"];
plan_cell.Label3.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer3"];
plan_cell.label4.text = [[tblArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"answer4"];


 return plan_cell;
 }

}
```

Comment: for above question it is right but not the right way to do in this way

Comment: @Imran -- can u explain little bit more

Comment: u r allocating cell indentifier twice , consuming more memory. this could be done by one allocation. just try

Comment: now fine , I submit my answer related to ? , may be questioner is the fresher , if I change something he does not understand the code then what is the use.

Comment: ya now it is fine. +1 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77579/discussion-between-imran-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning the cell outside the `if (tableView==table)`, so your program will NOT reach the code after it.

Instead of

```
if (tableView==table) {
    cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}return cell; //This line is wrong
```

You should do this:

```
if (tableView==table) {
    cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Should be inside the if scope
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanx dude for ur replies and Answer all ur answer are working good thank you once again

Comment: There are other ways to do the same thing you are doing ... try to keep your code cleaner and easy maintenable.. good coding!

Answer (score 1):

*Why you are doing such complex coding, Just simply provide different tag value for Table Views, and you are returning cell outside of your if condition which is wrong. Follow the below code.*

**Do a checking like this:-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {  
     if(tableView.tag==1)// Table 1
       {

           //load cell as per your choice
           //cell operations
           return cell;
        }
      else // Table 2
       {
         //load cell as per your choice
           //cell operations
           return cell;
        }
```

Comment: i think your answer is correct. but no need two write two return statement. you can write only one outside it will also works.

Comment: no because he is using a custom cell and a prototype cell, that is why I have mentioned two return statement.

Comment: but  no need to write two statements.

Comment: how you suppose to return  a single cell?

Comment: That can be done if you use prototype cell, I think the OP is using Custom Cell nib..

Comment: Thanx dude for ur replies and Answer all ur answer are working good thank you once again