# how to display the web services having arrays?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I had completed upto the create a new address but later on I don't have any idea how to implement as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYa2.png) and later I try to get the arrays by using the code shown below but unable to print there if possible how to implement the code as shown in image and all the data presented in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYa2.png) is of dynamic but I had placed some cells designed in storyboard and got into separate sections like images and buttons and after I got stuck here and the data I need to pass here is

```
{
  "Flat": [
    {
      "price": "$5.00", 
      "id": 11, 
      "name": "Fixed"
    }
  ], 
  "United Parcel Service": [
    {
      "price": "$109.12", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "worldwide Expedited"
    }, 
    {
      "price": "$120.18", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "worldwide Express saver"
    }
  ]
}
```

any help would be of great appreciation

```
 func shippingaddressURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.detailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func shippingmethodURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                let arrayss = jsonObj?.allKeys
                self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Flat") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                self.methodArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "United Parcel Service") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0){
           return 1
        }
        else if (section == 1){
            return detailsArray.count
        }else if (section == 2){
            return 1
        }else if (section == 3) {
            print(arrayss)
            return arrayss.count
        }else {
            return 1
        }
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath) as! imageTableViewCell
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 1{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = detailsArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Int =  arr["number"] as! Int
//            let checkIndex = arr["default"] as! Int
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: mobilenumber)
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addresscell", for: indexPath) as! newAddressTableViewCell
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 3{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingmethodcell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTableViewCell
//            print(arrayss)
            cell.methodLabel.text = arrayss[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "continuecell", for: indexPath) as! continueTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: i don't know how to display the data as shown in image that is flat and united parcel service these arrays both are dynamic and inside it there are dictionaries that is also dynamic it may increase or decrease how to display ? @KKRocks

Comment: Are you facing any parsing issue?

Comment: i know how to parse but in this need to dispaly arrays that is flat and united parcel service and below it i need to display dictionaries as shown in image how to display i don't know @AnilKukadeja

Comment: What exactly you want? Display data with radio buttons?

Comment: leave radio buttons i need to display data from web services and i need to display it on table view but i don't know how to display the got data as like in  my posted image @iUser

Comment: Just pass the objects and make an array of objects and populate the datasource accordingly. Let me know if you need any help!

Comment: i can save the arrays separately and remaining dictionaries how to save separately and to pass it to table view  ? @AnilKukadeja

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSBsf.png here is my design layout page till now i had completed

Comment: You will have one array of dictionary for "Flat" and one for "United Parcel Service". Now it depends upon your requirement which you want to show in tableview. Both are arrays and each array contains multiple dictionary objects. So I don't understand what do you mean by remaining dictionaries?

Comment: ya what u said is right i need to pass the multiple dictionaries inside it in Flat and United parcel service and both array names also i need to display onto a table view as shown below

Comment: So I hope your question is got answered right?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BQIE.png this part i don't know how to display ? @AnilKukadeja

Comment: in my original api i am having nearly 5 arrays like flat and united parcel service and inside it also it multiple dictionaries i need to display all of them including array names also in table view @AnilKukadeja

Comment: if possible any suggestion how to implement ?

Comment: Populate the main array and display it..

Comment: how i don't know can u illustrate with an example because i am new to swift 3

Comment: You need do more two kind of cell, one for title, another for check item.

Comment: how to implement any example ? @ovo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: sample]

Here is sample you want, hope it help.

```
class MyTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct ShipPrice {
        let title: String
        let name: String?
        let price: String?
        let id: Int?
    }

    var datas: [ShipPrice] = {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "content2", ofType: nil) else {
            fatalError("File not found.")
        }

        guard let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            fatalError("Open content failed.")
        }

        guard let data = content.data(using: .utf8) else {
            fatalError("Making data fialed.")
        }

        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) else {
            fatalError("JSON Serializetion failed.")
        }

        let parse: (String, [[String: Any]])->([ShipPrice]) = { title, datas in
            var shipPrices = [ShipPrice]()
            for data in datas {
                guard let id = data["id"] as? Int, let name = data["name"] as? String, let price = data["price"] as? String else {
                    fatalError("Data key not found.")
                }
                let shipPrice = ShipPrice(title: title, name: name, price: price, id: id)
                shipPrices.append(shipPrice)
            }
            return shipPrices
        }

        var shipPrices = [ShipPrice]()
        if let datas = json as? [String: Any]  {

            if let flats = datas["Flat"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                shipPrices.append(ShipPrice(title: "Flat", name: nil, price: nil, id: nil))
                shipPrices.append(contentsOf: parse("Flat", flats))
            }

            if let uPS = datas["United Parcel Service"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                shipPrices.append(ShipPrice(title: "United Parcel Service", name: nil, price: nil, id: nil))
                shipPrices.append(contentsOf: parse("United Parcel Service", uPS))
            }
        }
        return shipPrices
    }()

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return datas.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        if datas[indexPath.row].name == nil && datas[indexPath.row].price == nil {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
            cell.textLabel?.text = datas[indexPath.row].title
        }
        else { 
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = datas[indexPath.row].name! + datas[indexPath.row].price!
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to take a separate table view controller and i need to implement in it  ?

Comment: thanks bro exactly this is what i have been looking for

Comment: It's just a sample that show you how to implement you want, the point is how to create the data array.

Comment: where i need to pass the url in this ? @ovo

Comment: The data array is created from local file in this sample, thus there is no url need to pass it.

Comment: any alternative to this without using table view  ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkYa2.png in this image if i unselect the radio button then i need to hide the view of shipping method that is Flat and United parcel service section how to implement this

Comment: You could try reduce you number of sections and reload tableview.

Comment: i will reduce the sections but how to implement the arrays that is dynamic and the dictionaries inside it also dynamic

Comment: You can separate data models for each section, so when you get datas from server, you can easily to fill each data model.

Comment: then above code how it will be implemented in that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928295/ios-program-to-use-multiple-uitableview-in-a-single-uiviewcontroller can i try like this link ?

Comment: sure, trying is Wonderful.

Comment: help me bro i was trying from long time @ovo